# Subquery Results Differ When Selecting Entire Group

Tags: sql-server

I am working with the following query in SQL Server 2012.

When I run this I get the following.

However if I run this for all the **Antibacterials**, commenting out

```
AND THERAPEUTIC_CLASS_NAME IN ('Beta-lactam, Penicillins', 'Beta-lactam, Cephalosporins')
```

and making no other changes, the numbers don't match. I have been pulling my hair over why the results differ but to no avail. I appreciate any advice on this.

When selecting at a higher level.

Comment: It's probably because of the outer join. You didn't use aliases. Which table has `THERAPEUTIC_CLASS_NAME`?

Comment: You probably want either two inner joins or two left outer joins as well.

Comment: Well mixing the inner join after the left join is clearly wrong. `DISTINCT` is likely redundant with your `row_number()` expression. I'm not sure why you have. Using DRUGS.NDC for the partitioning seems odd too. What do you mean by higher level exactly? Only the outermost query has that `GPI_10_Count` column.

Comment: In the first screenshot I am only showing two members of the THERAPEUTIC_CATEGORY but in the second I have selected all members of THERAPEUTIC_CATEGORY. That's what I meant by higher level.

Comment: I am partitioning by DRUGS.NDC so I can rule out duplicates. If you see towards the bottom, I am only considering entries with ROWNUM = 1.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. And I just noticed that both partitioning and ordering by the same column makes no sense either.

Comment: Thanks. What else doesn't make sense here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70981/discussion-between-shawnt00-and-dombey).

Comment: It would help greatly if you aliased your columns in the `WHERE` clause. Then we could see if it 's the usual _where on an outer makes it inner_ issue.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Good point. Let me see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the row_number expression.

The same NDC can appear under multiple therapeutic classes but the row_numbering is not deterministic. Removing the filter caused many of those rows from the old query to get a different numbering and thus moved under a different category.

I'm not sure whether row_number is an appropriate fix to eliminate these duplicates but if it is then you'll have to add more ordering columns. (Ordering on the same column as the partition doesn't do anything either.)